# Two allowed paths in rsync command in authorized_keys

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, hp-ux

I have a question about rsync restriction in authorized_keys command. I need to copy files via rsync from one server to another without prompting password. There is no problem, but I need to specify two allowed paths in rsync command in authorized_keys.

This is for one destination paths and it works fine. But I need to specify the second allowed path (/test/dir2) for this ssh-key.

```
*from="test",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty,command="rsync --server /test/dir1" ssh-rsa .....*
```

My question is: How to setup for 2 allowed destinations using one ssh_key?